# fetching data in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, fetch

I am starting with angular 4 and server side rendering, currently I am trying to get a Proof of Concept fetching some data of one of my external API's. That API return a Json Object.

The site was rendering pretty well, however now that I included the call to fetch data it's not rendered and the response that I am getting doesn't seems to be what I should get.

In the app.components.ts I added:

```
 private apiUrl= 'https://myapi/Users';
  data: any = {};

  constructor(private http: Http){
    this.getUsers();
    this.getData();
  }

  getData(){
    let res=this.http.get(this.apiUrl).map((res: Response)=>res.json());
    console.log("result:",res)
    return res;
  }

  getUsers(){
    this.getData().subscribe(data=>{
      this.data=data;
    })
  }
```

Now, as you can see, in the getData method I am printing in console the result of the http calls, however I am getting this:

```
Observable {
  _isScalar: false,
  source: Observable { _isScalar: false, _subscribe: [Function] },
  operator: MapOperator { project: [Function], thisArg: undefined } }
```

Why I am not getting there the json object? which could be the reason?

Comment: That is correct. Your `res` is actually an `Observable`, not the data itself. Observables are asynchronous.  To see the real data, `console.log` it at your `subscribe()`. call back function, or you can peek it inside your `map` call back function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your getUsers() internally calls getData, you dont have to call again inside the constructor.

```
constructor(private http: Http){
    this.getUsers();
   //remove this line this.getData();
 }
```

also place the console.log inside the subscribe method to see the actual data,

```
getUsers(){
    this.getData().subscribe(data=>{
      this.data=data;
      console.log(this.data);
    })
  }
```

**EDIT**
As the below comment says, it is not recommended to have your method call inside constructor, make your components to implement ngOnit and add the method inside

Comment: To add to this ... it is not recommended to perform asynchronous operations in the constructor. Instead, use the ngOnInit life-cycle hook method. In addition, it is normally recommended to move data access into its own service. I have a complete example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-GettingStarted (in the APM-Final folder)